# The Jquery displays $20.099999999999998 instead of $20.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating-accuracy

This is the Jquery code：

```
  function Totalprice()
{
    var unitprice=$('#unitpay').val();
    var quota=$('#readers').val();
    var totalprice=unitprice*quota;
    $('#totalprice').text('$'+totalprice);

}
```

When the value of readers is 67 and the unitpay is 0.3, it calculates the total price and displays $20.099999999999998 , not $20.1. What's wrong? If I want it to display $20.1 instead of $20.099999999999998, how can I rewrite the code?

Comment: It's broken!!! The end is nighh!!

Comment: If it were for a gas station the display would be 20.1999999999999 ;-)

Comment: Of course, this has nothing to do with jQuery. This is a javascript/floating point problem.

Comment: It's a floating point problem, nothing to do with JavaScript. 1/10 can't be represented in a fixed number of binary digits, in the same way 1/3 can't be represented with a fixed number of decimal digits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
$('#totalprice').text('$'+totalprice.toFixed(1));
```

or:

```
$('#totalprice').text('$'+totalprice.toFixed(2));
```

to show it as an actual dollar amount.

Answer (score 5):

As your enthusiastic commentators pointed out, it's a [floating point error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).  The quick and easy solution is to use a rounding method like toFixed().

Answer (score 3):

Just use `.toFixed(2)`. [(link)](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html)

The problem is that computers can't represent some numbers exactly (they're finite, and operate in binary), so stuff like this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has some pretty severe floating point issues. Try typing 0.1+0.2 in your Firebug console sometime for some fun.

This isn't an issue with jQuery. As has been mentioned above, use toFixed().